What is a natural way to refer to the contents of a video, or text
비디오가 이에 대해 간호사는 어린이들을 지켰어요
Context: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/fCKJEffmPrM
Is this a natural way to say what a video is ABOUT ?

"is about (something" is expressed as -에 대한 것이다 or -에 관한 것이다 (대하다 is more general while 관하다 sounds a bit more specific, but they are largely synonyms).
대하다 (to face, deal with) and 관하다 (to pertain to; to be concerned with) are verbs, but they are used in the conjugated forms 대한/관한 (adjectival) or 대해/관해 (adverbial) when they mean what the subject is about.
(In dry language like legalese or formal notices, you might see 대한다 or 관한다 used as predicates.)
Your sentence is not right because the predicate has to be 대한 것이다 or 관한 것이다 (is about something), not 지켰어요 which is part of the thing being described.

(이/그) 비디오는 지진이 일어났을 때 간호사가 어린이들을 대피시킨 것에 대한 것이에요/거예요 = (This / The) video is about how a nurse evacuated children when an earthquake struck (대피시키다 = to evacuate people).

The first -는 것 is there to turn "nurse evacuated children" into a noun phrase, and the second -ㄴ 것 is to make the whole thing a noun phrase since 대하다 in this sense is not used directly as a final verb.
More commonly the topic part is given in a simpler (non-clause) noun phrase, as in the following examples.

뉴스는 어제 지진이 일어난 것에 대한 거였어요 = The news was about (the fact) that there was an earthquake yesterday.
뉴스는 어제 일어난 지진에 대한 거였어요 = The news was about the earthquake that occurred yesterday.

#1 is longer and more cumbersome, so #2 is usually preferred in simple phrasing.
Similar structure for your example would be 비디오는 지진 상황 중 간호사의 어린이 대피에 대한 거였어요 = The video was about a nurse evacuating children during an  earthquake situation.  But using the 것에 대한 것이다 form might be more clear for complex structures like this (there are other variations too, like -는/ㄴ지에 대한 것이다, using another noun phrase maker 지).

Great answer, thank you.
